# Linear models in R with different combinations of variables

Tags: r, variables, automation, lm

I am new to R and I am stuck with a problem. I am trying to read a set of data in a table and I want to perform linear modeling. Below is how I read my data and my variables names:

```
>data =read.table(datafilename,header=TRUE)
>names(data)
[1] "price"     "model"     "size"   "year"   "color"
```

What I want to do is create several linear models using different combinations of the variables (price being the target ), such as:

```
> attach(data)
> model1 = lm(price~model+size)
> model2 = lm(price~model+year)
> model3 = lm(price~model+color)
> model4 = lm(price~model+size)
> model4 = lm(price~size+year+color)
#... and so on for all different combination...
```

My main aim is to compare the different models. Is there a more clever way to generate these models instead of hard coding the variables, especially that the number of my variables in some cases will increase to 13 or so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to get all of the combinations of variables using the `combn` function. It's a bit messy, and uses a loop (perhaps someone can improve on this with `mapply`):

```
vars <- c("price","model","size","year","color")
N <- list(1,2,3,4)
COMB <- sapply(N, function(m) combn(x=vars[2:5], m))
COMB2 <- list()
k=0
for(i in seq(COMB)){
    tmp <- COMB[[i]]
    for(j in seq(ncol(tmp))){
        k <- k + 1
        COMB2[[k]] <- formula(paste("price", "~", paste(tmp[,j], collapse=" + ")))
    }
}
```

Then, you can call these formulas and store the model objects using a `list` or possibly give unique names with the `assign` function:

```
res <- vector(mode="list", length(COMB2))
for(i in seq(COMB2)){
    res[[i]] <- lm(COMB2[[i]], data=data)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If your goal is model selection there are several tools available in R which attempt to automate this process. Read the documentation on `dredge(...)` in the [`MuMIn` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MuMIn/MuMIn.pdf).

```
# dredge: example of use
library(MuMIn)
df <- mtcars[,c("mpg","cyl","disp","hp","wt")]  # subset of mtcars
full.model <- lm(mpg ~ cyl+disp+hp+wt,df)       # model for predicting mpg
dredge(full.model)
# Global model call: lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + wt, data = df)
# ---
# Model selection table 
#    (Intrc)     cyl      disp       hp     wt df   logLik  AICc delta weight
# 10   39.69 -1.5080                    -3.191  4  -74.005 157.5  0.00  0.291
# 14   38.75 -0.9416           -0.01804 -3.167  5  -72.738 157.8  0.29  0.251
# 13   37.23                   -0.03177 -3.878  4  -74.326 158.1  0.64  0.211
# 16   40.83 -1.2930  0.011600 -0.02054 -3.854  6  -72.169 159.7  2.21  0.096
# 12   41.11 -1.7850  0.007473          -3.636  5  -73.779 159.9  2.37  0.089
# 15   37.11         -0.000937 -0.03116 -3.801  5  -74.321 161.0  3.46  0.052
# 11   34.96         -0.017720          -3.351  4  -78.084 165.6  8.16  0.005
# 9    37.29                            -5.344  3  -80.015 166.9  9.40  0.003
# 4    34.66 -1.5870 -0.020580                  4  -79.573 168.6 11.14  0.001
# 7    30.74         -0.030350 -0.02484         4  -80.309 170.1 12.61  0.001
# 2    37.88 -2.8760                            3  -81.653 170.2 12.67  0.001
# 8    34.18 -1.2270 -0.018840 -0.01468         5  -79.009 170.3 12.83  0.000
# 6    36.91 -2.2650           -0.01912         4  -80.781 171.0 13.55  0.000
# 3    29.60         -0.041220                  3  -82.105 171.1 13.57  0.000
# 5    30.10                   -0.06823         3  -87.619 182.1 24.60  0.000
# 1    20.09                                    2 -102.378 209.2 51.68  0.000
```

You should consider these *tools* to help you make intelligent decisions. *Do not let the tool make the decision for you!!!*

For example, in this case `dredge(...)` suggests that the "best" model for predicting `mpg`, based on the AICc criterion, includes `cyl` and `wt`. But note that AICc for this model is 157.7 whereas the second best model has an AICc of 157.8, so these are basically the same. In fact, the first 5 models in this list are not significantly different in their ability to predict `mpg`. It does, however, narrow things down a bit. Among these 5, I would want to look at distribution of residuals (should be normal), trends in residuals (there should be none), and leverage (do some points have undue influence), before picking a "best" model.

Comment: Does this work for non linear models, like `full.model <- lm(log(mpg) ~ cyl+disp+hp+wt,df)`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `stepwise multiple regression` to determine what variables make sense to include. To get this started you write one `lm()` statement with all variables, such as:

```
library(MASS)
fit <- lm(price ~ model + size + year + color)
```

Then you continue with:

```
step <- stepAIC(model, direction="both")
```

Finally, you can use to following to show the results:

```
step$anova
```

Hope this gives you some inspiration for advancing your script.

Comment: `step` does not guarantee that all model combinations will be fit.

Comment: Is there an advantage of `MASS::stepAIC` over the built-in `stats::step`?