# Iterate over list and append in order to do a regression in R

Tags: r, regression, lm

I know that somewhere there will exist this kind of question, but I couldn't find it. I have the variables `a, b, c, d` and I want to write a loop, such that I regress and append the variables and regress again with the additional variable

`lm(Y ~ a, data = data)`, then
`lm(Y ~ a + b, data = data)`, then

`lm(Y ~ a + b + c, data = data)` etc.

How would you do this?

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955617/linear-models-in-r-with-different-combinations-of-variables

Comment: The problem is that in that post, he is seeking for all possible combinations. What I need is just to keep that simple flow. First a, then a and b, then a and b and c and at last a and b and c and d.

Comment: Better to ask as a new question in a separate post, and link to this one.

Comment: Alright, I'll follow your advice.

Comment: And please consider accepting one of the answers so we can have this question as solved.

Comment: Perhaps you need `?add1` function? It essentially does what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vars = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
# might want to use a subset of names(data) instead of
# manually typing the names

reg_list = list()
for (i in seq_along(vars)) {
  my_formula = as.formula(sprintf('Y ~ %s', paste(vars[1:i], collapse = " + ")))
  reg_list[[i]] = lm(my_formula, data = data)
}
```

You can then inspect an individual result with, e.g., `summary(reg_list[[2]])` (for the 2nd one).

Answer (score 3):

Using *paste* and *as.formula*, example using ***mtcars*** dataset:

```
myFits <- lapply(2:ncol(mtcars), function(i){
  x <- as.formula(paste("mpg", 
                        paste(colnames(mtcars)[2:i], collapse = "+"), 
                        sep = "~"))
  lm(formula = x, data = mtcars)
})
```

**Note:** looks like a duplicate post, I have seen a better solution for this type of questions, cannot find at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with a `lapply` / `reformulate` approach.

```
formulae <- lapply(ivars, function(x) reformulate(x, response="Y"))
lapply(formulae, function(x) summary(do.call("lm", list(x, quote(dat)))))
```

***Data***

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(80), 20, 4, dimnames=list(NULL, c("Y", letters[1:3]))))
ivars <- sapply(1:3, function(x) letters[1:x])  # create an example vector ov indep. variables
```